# Как сравнить два массива в JavaScript ( так же подключен NODE JS )

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js

Я пишу программу. И мне требуется сравнить внутренности двух массивов. Внутри массивов лежат строки. Такие как, например, 'help'. Данные массивы у меня заполняются от http запроса строками. Данные строки у меня занесены в SetInterval. А вначале интервала данные массива сохраняются перед новым перебором. Мне требуется, чтобы после нового перебора программа сравнивала внутренности двух массивов и выводила мне тот элемент, которые присутствует в одном массиве, но отсутствует в другом.
Вот некое подобие того, что я хочу воссоздать.:

```
var s1=[];
var s2=[]; // saved information from request
setInterval(function({
 s2 = s1;
 for ( счетчик, условие перебора, счетчик++ ) { 
     s1.push(элемент от запроса);
 }
 if ( счетчик == 0 ) {

 } else {
  Вот здесь мне нужно сравнить элементы массива.
 }
}, 1000)
```

Пример того, что я подразумеваю под "сравнить":

```
var s1 = [lol, k, iase, kda];
var s2 = [k, lol, kda];
var s3 = Элементу который есть в 1-ом массиве, но отсутствует во втором.
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Надеюсь, что сейчас вопрос стал более нагляден и лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function diff(a, b) {
    return a.filter(function(i) {return b.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};

var arr1 = ['lol', 'k', 'iase', 'kda'],
    arr2 = ['k', 'lol', 'kda'];

console.log(diff(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Данная функция принимает 2 массива, сортирует их методом sort() и одним цыклом проходит сквозь них возвращая первое неравенство.

```js
const compareArrays = (arr1, arr2) => {
    let len = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length);
    let sorted1 = arr1.sort();
    let sorted2 = arr2.sort();

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (sorted1[i] !== sorted2[i])
            return sorted1[i] || sorted2[i];
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.